# Update rotation draggable jQuery UI 1.8.18 to UI 1.11.4

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, rotation, jquery-ui-droppable

The rotation draggable it works perfectly in version UI 1.8.18:

http://jsfiddle.net/avPf6/1/

But in version UI 1.11.4 does not work this part:

```
drag: function(event, ui){
    var rotateCSS = 'rotate(' + ui.position.left + 'deg)';

    $(this).parent().css({
        '-moz-transform': rotateCSS,
        '-webkit-transform': rotateCSS
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/avPf6/1/

How do I properly update this function to work in the current version of the jquery ui?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the `handle` has some upgradation in 1.11.4 can check [here](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.11/)

You don't need `handle` as the element for the drag(rotate here) to occur is on the draggable element itself.

**Working solution:**

```
$('#handle').draggable({  
    opacity: 0.01, 
    helper: 'clone',
    drag: function(event, ui ){
        console.log(ui);
        var rotateCSS = 'rotate(' + ui.position.left + 'deg)';

        $(this).parent().css({
            '-moz-transform': rotateCSS,
            '-webkit-transform': rotateCSS
        });
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/avPf6/1056/)

Comment: it work, thanks. How do I have a motion that follow with your mouse correctly? e.g:  http://godswearhats.com/jquery-ui-rotatable/demo.html

Comment: They used a plugin jquery-ui-rotatable link: (you know)https://github.com/godswearhats/jquery-ui-rotatable. use `$('#handle').rotatable();` and `draggable` and include jquery-rotate.js and css too